# how do I open my live site locally in MAMP?

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I've been trying for weeks to open my live site locally in mamp pro so i can retheme it.  I asked MAMP for support last week on this but I still haven't heard back. I upgraded to mamp pro but I still can't get my site opened. The servers start. I had found a video here [opening a live site in mamp pro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVrQvvR5zXo) I haven't found any from MAMP on youtube for how to open a live site locally

I have my DB in the DB folder of mamp, I made an archive of my site with duplicator and copied it into htdocs as per the video link but I can't get to the site to work on it

I really need this working as I can't retheme my live site and I need this done during our shut down this week. I need Mamp working to do it

I'm attaching some images. If anyone knows what I need to do, please tell me.

Comment: Do you have downloaded copy of your website?

Comment: I've made a duplicator package plus I exported the db. I also have a local copy of all files in filezilla.  so i think i have everything but feel free to chip in if I missed something.  I copied the duplicator package to htdocs & imported the DB

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76FVq.png)After weeks of trial and error I have the solution. Start Over! Delete Mamp. Re-download it and wordpress and follow this link https://skillcrush.com/2015/04/14/install-wordpress-mac/ to the letter. It took me several tries but I got it working. I then made a packet with duplicator pro and pasted both the archive and installation.php file in Applications >Mamp>htdocs folder and use the url [enter link description here][2]

sorry i tried to show an image of my site working on localhost but i don't have 10 points yet so i can't embed an image. I can prove this works if i get more points i guess.